# Vue 3, parsing nested json data from POST

Tags: json, vue.js, dictionary, post, vuejs3

I am trying to parse some data from a POST request.
I have successfully used both Fetch and Axios, however my issue is parsing the JSON.
The JSON I get is in the following format:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "item": {
        "token": {
            "value": "123123123123123"
        }
    }
}
```

In the Fetch example I am using:

```
const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ username: "test1", password: "test1" })
  };

fetch('url', requestOptions)
    //.then(response => response.token.json())
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.tokens = data)
    .catch(err => console.log(err.message))
}
```

Then when I am trying to display the result I do:

```
<div v-for="(t) in tokens" :key="t.item">
        <div>
          Fetch: {{ t.token }}
        </div>
</div>
```

....

```
export default {
  name: "Header",
  data() {
    return {     
      tokens: []
    };
  },
```

Now if I do:

Fetch: {{ t }}  -> I get the whole object.

If I do:  Fetch: {{ t.token}} -> I get the item, like:

```
"value": "123123123123123"
```

However if I try to get the token ( 1 level deeper ), by doing:

```
Fetch: {{ t.token.value }}
```

Then I get nothing at all.

Comment: I don't see any key within your objects named `token`, it's `t.item.value` to get the token value as far as we can see.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - just tried it, doesn work. Kicks back:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value') in Dev tools.

Comment: Actually is `t.item.token.value`

Comment: @Radeanu that also didn't work with a similar error:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'token')

I actually realized I had a type in my initial post: t.token works for me, t.token.value doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was in the way my data was defined.
I had to follow to exact JSON format that is expected:

```
tokens: 
        {
            status: "",
                item: {
                    token: {
                        value: ""
                    }
                }
        }
```

I am now able to access to value by doing:

```
Fetch: {{ tokens.item.token.value }}
```